# Indeterminate progress bar not working properly

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, mat-card

I am using MatProgressBarModule to add a linear indeterminate status bar at end of card-footer. Below is my code -

```
  <mat-card-footer>
    <ng-content select="dashboard-card-footer"></ng-content>
    <section class="example-section">
    <mat-progress-bar  [mode]="indeterminate"  value="20" bufferValue ="75"> 
    </mat-progress-bar>
    </section>
  </mat-card-footer>
```

It shows on screen as determinate status bar. I have tried with different modes too i.e. query,buffer. But it only works as a determinate progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `[]` (it should be used when you want to bind value with any object/variable) for defining mode, as `indeterminate` is not component variable but only string. Also no need of `value` & `bufferValue`. Modify your code as:

```
<mat-card-footer>
    <ng-content select="dashboard-card-footer"></ng-content>
    <section class="example-section">
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    </section>
</mat-card-footer>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for prompt reply. I started with the answered approach. Still it's not showing as indeterminate bar. I tried following example present here https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/examples

Comment: It doesn't show animated movement as present in above mentioned site.

Comment: can you create stackblitz?

Comment: it should work, I forked example and changed the mode. It's wokring https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-astjm1. Make sure to import animation module. https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 3):

Try to check, maybe you have imports: NoopAnimationsModule, cause it will disable all animations for your app)